# How to avoid parent dialog component that is closed by a child dialog template reference

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a component that is a dialog (user creation form).

```
this.dialog.open(AddUserComponent, { restoreFocus: true });
```

This component opens another dialog via a template reference (to avoid creating tons of components for simple paragraphs...)

```html
<mat-dialog-content>
    <!-- user creation form -->
</mat-dialog-content>
</mat-dialog-actions>
  <button (click)="submit()">
    create
  </button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
<!-- ------------- confirmation dialog ------------- -->
<ng-template #confirmDialog>
  <h2 matDialogTitle>confirmation dialog</h2>
  <mat-dialog-content>
    <p>are you sure ?/p>
  </mat-dialog-content>
  <mat-dialog-actions align="end">
    <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>
    close
    </button>
  </mat-dialog-actions>
</ng-template>
```

```
@ViewChild('confirmDialog') public confirmDialog!: TemplateRef<any>;

public submit() {
  this.dialog.open(this.confirmDialog);
}
```

My problem is that when I click the "close" button on my confirmation dialog, the parent dialog closes. Keeping the child dialog open.

**Expected:**

I wish that when I press the "close" button it would close the dialog itself (child dialog) and not the others (parent dialog).

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-template-mat-dialog-eeg7uy?file=app/app.component.html)

Thanks for helping

Comment: please share a working stackblitz with the issue replicate and expected result!

Comment: @NarenMurali I updated the above post with Stackblitz, and there was already the expected result, tell me if the information is not understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `disableClose` attribute as `true` to the parent component dialog.

```
this.dialog.open(this.confirmDialog, { disableClose: true });
```

Dialog gets close only on, call the close method programmatically.

```
this.dialogRef.close();
```